# Flink Kafka Connector with DeliveryGuarantee.EXACTLY_ONCE producing duplicate messages

Tags: apache-flink, apache-kafka-connect, flink-streaming, exactly-once

## **My Verions:**

- flink.version  1.15.2
- scala.binary.version 2.12
- java.version 1.11

---

## **My Code:**

`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("commit.offsets.on.checkpoint", "true"); 
KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
.setBootstrapServers(kafkaBroker)
.setTopics("inputTopic")
.setGroupId("my-group"+ System.currentTimeMillis())
.setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets(OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST))
.setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
.setProperties(prop)
.build(); 
DataStream<String> sourceStream = env.fromSource(
source,
WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source");  
Properties sinkProps = new Properties(); 
sinkProps.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG, 6000); 
KafkaSink<String> sink = KafkaSink.<String>builder()
.setBootstrapServers(kafkaBroker)
.setKafkaProducerConfig(sinkProps)
.setRecordSerializer(new OffsetSerializer("outputTopic"))
.setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.EXACTLY_ONCE)
.setTransactionalIdPrefix("trx-"+System.currentTimeMillis())
.build();  
sourceStream
.keyBy(new KeySelector<String, String>(){ 
@Override
public String getKey(String value) throws Exception {
System.out.println("Key >>" + value); 
return value;
} 
})
.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
@Override public String map(String value) throws Exception {  
System.out.println("offset >>" + value);
if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
{  
System.out.println("Custom unhandled exception");
throw new Exception("Custom unhandled exception");
} 
return value; 
}
}) 
.sinkTo(sink);
env.enableCheckpointing(500);
env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(10000);
env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
env.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(10L);
env.getCheckpointConfig().setTolerableCheckpointFailureNumber(1);
env.getCheckpointConfig().setExternalizedCheckpointCleanup(
ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.NO_EXTERNALIZED_CHECKPOINTS);
env.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(1
,org.apache.flink.api.common.time.Time.of(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS)));
env.execute("tester");
}  `
```

---

## **I Tried:**

- Checked if transactions are enabled working for kafka cluster
- Changed TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG
- Changed consumer group id for every run
- Removing keyby on dataStrea
- Adding

> env.getCheckpointConfig().setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1);
> env.getCheckpointConfig().enableUnalignedCheckpoints();

- Using different types of ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup

---

## **My Plea:**

I am expecting this code to produce one message on Kafka per consumed message. But on exception it is reprocessing messages that successfully completed the stream in a previous run
Help!

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are using different Transaction Ids everytime you produce the record set. While restart of your app using checkpoint, flink will not know the stable transaction id.

Flink setTransactionalIdPrefix Comment-

> It is important to keep the prefix stable across application restarts. If the prefix
> * changes it might happen that lingering transactions are not correctly aborted and newly
> * written messages are not immediately consumable until the transactions timeout

i.e. Instead of
`.setTransactionalIdPrefix("trx-"+System.currentTimeMillis())`

Use this -
`.setTransactionalIdPrefix("trx-stable-1");`

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Transaction id prefix is once assinged it will be same throughout the application life cycle, although i have attached dynamic prefix, it will use same prefix at restart of streamExecution environement.The actual issue was at the consumer end. the duplicate messages which was generated was having read_uncommited, If messages produced by the sink gets consumed by kafka consumer with isolation.level = read_commited, it solves my problem